# How can edit the gridview cell value on click of the gridview cell, in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, mysql, gridview, aspxgridview

In my website, I have a gridview which has datasource dynamically bound from database table.

Now I want that when a user clicks in a cell of the gridview it becomes editable and he can edit the cell values and update the database accordingly.

I don't wish to use the in-built edit, delete and update buttons of gridview. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Inside awareness cell declare (for example) div or span with specified ID.
2. Using javascript declare `onclick` handler for this div/span
3. Follow this simplest example http://weblogs.asp.net/mnolton/archive/2003/06/04/8260.aspx

Comment: So how will it help in updating the changes back into the database?

Comment: @PARTH, note that written relates to non-ajax approach. When postback event handled you just need call `GridView.SetEditRow` method. That will show grid in edit mode. Number of row you can code in javascript, so it will be pass as argument of event

Comment: Is there any code available which I can refer to. It would help me understand that in a better way.

Comment: @PARTH - you are really lazy :)  5 seconds googling I've found next sample: http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/08/04/gridview-row-click-selection-via-clientside-code.aspx

Comment: @Dewfy: Its not about being lazy but I can google it only when I understand what actually you are trying to say. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @PARTH - I hope technique described in my answer help you to understand entire example. By the way, there is another approach - but it uses AJAX, and concerned with writing special web-services to manage editing

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you catch the client side click on the grid you can them force a post back in which you set the selected row to edit mode. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: I am not very clear about what you just said. Can you please elaborate a bit more on what you just said.